# Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from (Object)=>int to int using Java Xtend

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xtend, krypton

I'm having an error when splitting data extract from excel. when I'm on `a.java` it works. But now I'm converting my scripts to Java Xtend and now I am having the following error.

[image]

Here is the code

```
var dashboards = M3ASmokeTest.ReadExcelFile();
var countdsh = 0;
var countdom = 0;
var countrep = 0;
Thread.sleep(20000);
for(String groupedDomain: dashboards)
{
    var domain = dashboards.get(countdom).split(";")[0];
    var dboards = dashboards.get(countdsh).split(";")[1];
    var reports = dashboards.get(countdsh).split(";")[2];'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must admit, I don't know xtend, but from the docs it says :

https://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/2.3.0/Documentation.pdf page 39

> When a method call’s last parameter is a lambda it can be passed right
> after the parameter list. For instance if you want to sort some
> strings by their length, you could write :
>
> Collections::sort(someStrings) [ a, b | a.length - b.length ]

So the square brackets denote lambda expressions, which is what you're getting (so I'm guessing a bug in xtend that it's incorrectly trying to apply that in your case).

Since it appears xtend automatically converts Arrays to Lists (page 15), try replacing the [0] with get(0), so :

```
var domain = dashboards.get(countdom).split(";").get(0);
```

Comment: issue is still the same :(

Comment: it is now working forgot to change the square bracket. Thank you so much!